# change data in table Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table:

```
| code   |  name  |
|--------|--------|
| A      |  name1 |
| A      |  name2;name3 |
```

I want to change data in table:

```
| code   |  name  |
|--------|--------|
| A      |  name1 |
| A      |  name2 |
| A      |  name3 |
```

How do it?
Please help me!

Comment: Does the names column always have just one name or two separated by a semi colon?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: The name column maybe: 'name1' or 'name1;name3' or 'name1;name2;name3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
    code,
    unnest(string_to_array("name", ';'))
from codename
```

## Demo

Comment: Wow! Thanks @tim-biegeleisen for the demo. It is really nice to see it working.